# Two column blocks with image and text

Tags: html, css, image

I'm looking to create something like in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aoxt5.png) image.

Each block would have an image (a square image) and text.

Anyone has any clue how to design it? I prefer a CSS solution.

Thanks!

Comment: What code do you have so far?  Where is your technical question?

Comment: You're not posing an actual problem here. From what you write, of course it can be done. When you say CSS you're probably thinking HTML. Just have 4 divs, put your images and content in there and arange the divs. However you want. Start here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp or even here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_basic.asp

Comment: @Lokase : This is just a part of the whole layout that I am building. I had a problem with what I had tried by then, kept fidgeting with image properties and I didn't try div (stupid of me, I know). The answer from Chin seems good enough to solve my problem.
Thanks :).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As others have commented, your question is a bit vague. However, I have done a quick mashup on [jdFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chin/YW6FN/1/). The pattern background can be achieved by CSS3 patterns although they are not fully compatible with older browsers. I have used border-radius CSS to create rounded corners in the boxes. Have a look at it and hopefully should give you an idea on how to go about doing your won one. Also recommend looking at w3schools links submitted on above above comments.